# update a row in an sql table with an image

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to update a row in an sql table with an image. The row already contains id, name, type, etc. But when I use the update below I get "System.Windows.Controls.Image" inserted into the row.

```
partner.AdImageUrl = uri.ToString();//"url + name"

sc.Open();
//cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Table1 set Name = '" + this.txtName.Text + "', AdType = '" + txttype + "', AdImageUrl = '" + imaPartners + "', Description = '" + txtDesc + "' where Name = '" + this.txtName.Text + "'");

cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Table1 Set AdImageUrl= '" + imaPartners +"' where Name = '" + this.txtName.Text + "'", sc); 
cmd.Connection = sc; 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Well what is `imaPartners`?

Comment: If the `imaPartners` is an Image control then placing it within a string will be equivalent to using the `.toString()` method of the object.

Comment: Are you trying to insert an Image URL or an images actual data?

Comment: Imapartners .uri, and pls do not concatenation your query, use sqlparameters, otherwise most likely your query would be invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If do you need to have AdImageUrl field with image url and imaPartners as an image.
Try imaPartners.Url or simil.
If not works, where is the declaration of imaPartners?

Comment: ok, imaPartners is an image control from wpf. This is filled from a blob. AdImageUrl is the column I need to insert the url of the image.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see imaPartners is an image control and it seem that AdImageUrl needs the image control URL so use:

```
imaPartners.ImageUrl
```